# Loading a custom css into a WebComponent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component

My goal is to load a custom css file that I have in a module ( https://github.com/raduzoom/dzs-chip-selector ) into a WebComponent ( defined in the same module )

The code is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-cqqwbe?file=src/App.js

When I am not using react, I add the style as a child of the component, and then load the style from the WebComponent code:

```
          <dzs-chip-selector ref={this.myRef} data-persistentOptions={JSON.stringify(this.chipSelectorOptions)}>
            <link rel="stylesheet" data-lazy-href="dzs-chip-selector/style/skins/skin-default.css"/>
          </dzs-chip-selector>
```

This works fine, but does not work in React because when rendering, the web component
is passed without children to the engine.

What I have done is **EJECT** react scripts, use the web component in **ref** - `ref={this.myRef}`, then loading the style in an async way

```
    async function loadCss(){

      import('chip-selector/dist/style/skins/skin-default.css').then((...args) => {
        const cssStyle = args[0].default[0][1];
        $myRef.wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', `<style>${cssStyle}</style>`)
      })

    }
```

This works, but it is hackish. And when I tried to include the code into StackBlitz, it errors out. Is there an other way that is less hackish and works in StackBlitz ?

---

---

---

###### interesting: *Response from ChatGPT*

first prompt, which I already tried before his suggestion, seems like my code +- a few array indexes

[image]

then I explained further what I need, like I did in this post

[image]

Quite impressed it understood my query. Never used that library, so I'm going to try this long shot, but do you have any better suggestions ?

*PS: Also found this article - https://www.wpeform.io/blog/render-react-app-shadow-dom-styled-components/ - maybe ChatGPT put me on the right path, even if that's not exactly the answer from my first try*

Comment: A quick note to anyone answering this: While the asker has included some ChatGPT queries in their question (which isn't ideal, but probably isn't big problem), using ChatGPT to generate an answer to this question is against StackOverflow rules: [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)

Comment: Including your css like this is also likely to break any local paths (imports, relative URLs...), so it's not advised. Why not add `<link />` element instead and wait for its load event?

Comment: @DBS , I understand what you are saying

That was just a interesting sidenote, but nonetheless could have proven to indicate a correct library

this is a personal project, so I will look for further solution in my free time after the job

Comment: @somethinghere I would have preffered to lazy load it, but I don ' t think I can without absolute urls -- that is the challange

Comment: That makes no sense. You can do that easily with just a `<link />` tag instead of an embedded `style` tag.

Comment: @somethinghere yeah, this is what I done - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-btq4kq?file=App.tsx - and it's async but you need absolute url